# JSON - key value pair not containing full data

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to fetch all the tables and their columns metadata present in the database in json format.

in the json file, the tablename key value pair is showing only the last table in the database and not all.
My code is below:

```java
ResultSet tables = databaseMetaData.getTables(catalog, schemaPattern, tableNamePattern, types);

while (tables.next()) {
    String tableName = tables.getString(3);
    jsonObject.put("tablename", tablename);
    ResultSet columnMetadata = databaseMetaData.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
    while (columnMetadata.next()) {
        JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
        record.put("Field_Name", columnMetadata.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
        record.put("Field_Length", columnMetadata.getString("COLUMN_SIZE"));
        array.put(record);
    }
    jsonObject.put("field", array);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add what data is being stored in `tables` from query response?

Comment: You are replacing the same key-values in `jsonObject` on each iteration over `tables`.  It seems like you want to create a separate JsonObject for each entry in `tables` and add it to a JsonArray, no?